# syntax error - sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to write a query in SQL but I get a syntax error in access.  i have check various code checkers online but they all say there are no issues.  Can anyone help?

```
   SELECT
      PROJECT.ProjectID,
      PROJECT.Name,
      PROJECT.Department,
      EMPLOYEE.EmployeeNumber,
      EMPLOYEE.LastName,
      EMPLOYEE.FirstName,
      EMPLOYEE.Phone 
   FROM
     ASSIGNMENT 
     INNER JOIN
         EMPLOYEE 
         ON ASSIGNMENT.EmployeeNumber = EMPLOYEE.EmployeeNumber 
     INNER JOIN
         PROJECT 
         ON ASSIGNMENT.ProjectID = PROJECT.ProjectID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access requires parentheses for multiple `JOIN`s:

```
FROM (ASSIGNMENT INNER JOIN
      EMPLOYEE 
      ON ASSIGNMENT.EmployeeNumber = EMPLOYEE.EmployeeNumber 
     ) INNER JOIN
      PROJECT 
      ON ASSIGNMENT.ProjectID = PROJECT.ProjectID;
```

Comment: OMG Thank you so much.  I knew it had to be something simple.